# aria2c: very slow to download even with multiple connections

Tags: aria2

versions: aria2-1.19.3-win-64bit-build1

I have an url to a file (80mb) which with other download tools I can have as many as 32 simultaneous connection to the server and download the file with 2mb/s but using aria2c it's speed is always under 100kb/s. what is wrong? any other switch that I should use?

What I'm using:

```
aria2c -x10 http://abc.exe
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

According to your screenshot, it uses 4 segments to download.

You can increase the number of segments using [`-s`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-s) option.

If you want to download using 16 simultaneous connections, try

```
aria2c -s16 -x16 http://abc.exe
```

Comment: You should now -x is capped at 16

Comment: `-s16 -x16` woks very well for me